# Laravel json does not return response

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am trying to return the response from my controller. But this is not working.

Here is my ajax.

```
 $('#pincode').on('change', function() {
     //const formData = $('#formid').serializeArray();
     var address = $("input[name=address]").val();
     var pincode= $("input[name=pincode]").val();
     var price = $("input[name=price]").val();
     var city = $("input[name=city]").val();
     var country =$('#country').val();
     var state = $('#state').val();
     //var state =$(this).val();
     //console.log(formData);
     $.ajaxSetup({
         headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
         }
     });
     $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         data:{address:address, pincode:pincode, price:price,country:country,state:state,city:city},
         url:'./ava',
         dataType: "json",
         success:function(data){
             console.log(data);
             alert(data.success);
         }

     });
 });
```

And here is my Controller. This return JSON array. But the problem with JSON response

```
$tb = new Avalara\TransactionBuilder($client, "AGELESSZENINC", Avalara\DocumentType::C_SALESINVOICE, 'ABC');
$t = $tb->withAddress('SingleLocation',$address,null,null, $city,$state,$pincode, $country)
    ->withLine($price, 1, null, "P0000000")
    ->create();
// echo('<h2>Transaction #1</h2>');
// echo('<pre>' . json_encode($t, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>');
   return response()->json(['success'=>$t]);
```

Output of `return response()->json(['success'=>$t]);` is json array.
Any Help Regarding to this.

Comment: "_Output of return response()->json(['success'=>$t]); is json array._" ?? So is it working or not? And _what exactly_ isn't working?

Comment: kerbholz@this part is not working ,success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                 alert(data.success);
               }

Comment: kerbholz@success response it's not working.

Comment: Have you used your browser's DevTools Network tab to make sure the response actually gets sent/is correct? And also maybe change all of your `data` in your `success` function to something like `response`, since `data` is already used above (not sure about this one though). Define "_is not working_": does nothing get printed to the console? Or does something wrong get printed?

Comment: What part of that is not working? Is it not logging `data`? Is no `alert()` being shown?  Maybe setup a `.error()` function on your ajax call to handle your Controller logic not working, and check your log `storage/logs/laravel.log` for any errors.

Comment: kerbholz@response data is to large , if DataType:"text" then Alert box is working with undefined, but when this is "json" .It's does not response ,

Comment: Tim Lewis@can you help me with a modified value

Comment: If you want to ping someone, you need to put the `@` symbol **before their name**, like `@TimLewis`. And what do you mean "help you with a modified value"? I've stated what you need to look for, and that you need to set up an `error()` function on your `$.ajax()` call. You have `success()`, but if the controller fails, you need an `error()` to handle that.

Comment: Tim Lewis@can you modified my ajax method with your answere

Comment: @Tim Lewis  please et me know

Comment: Much better. But no, you can find how to write a proper `$.ajax()` request here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Answer (score 0):

well maybe you should try

```
var resp = JSON.stringify(data);                   
console.log(resp);
```

just to see what's being sent back